# jquery mobile css not applied to knockout template

Tags: jquery, templates, knockout.js

im working on a jquery mobile project, and i want to use knockout as i understand mvvm very well, and thought it would speed up my project.  what i have is a viewmodel with an array of elements, and when i create a template for those elements and put a button inside the template, it does not get templated with jquery mobile css.

check out the js fiddle here: [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z9sbC/2/)

I would like the buttons of the players to get their styles from jquery, like the button on the bottom of the page (which is not in the template).

This is just an example, I would like this to be applied to other form elements as well, is there any good solution for this problem?

Comment: Markup updated by knockout based on viewmodel changes will pretty much always result in markup that isn't styled by jqm. Custom bindings seem to be the universal answer. Does anyone know of a collection of such bindings? Such a collection would go a long way towards making jqm and ko play nicely together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me share with you a bit of knowledge about how jQueryMobile works.

When a page is initialized, jQueryMobile iterates over all nodes with `data-...` attributes and makes them Mobile controls by modifying the DOM in order to implement these changes.

Your button is placed within the `<script type="text/html">` tag, so jQM cannot reach it. This is because the browser does not parse content in the`script` tag.

The usual way of avoiding this problem is to implement a custom binding for KO which will initialize the current node as a button. Please checkout my version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/romanych/z9sbC/3/